# rfvgyhnbgt - puzzle involving using keys

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

I was sent this puzzle without much context. The only advice I was given is that the puzzle involves using keys.

> rfvgyhnbgt rfvgyhntgbnjuyefvgbhu cfthngrfvtygnrfvtyghbn tghybygbnjutgbnju

Comment: Is there any context for this puzzle, or is it just the string of numbers?

Comment: I wasn't given context, but he told me it involves using keys

Comment: The letters are all adjacent on QWERTY keyboard. Have you tried tracing them out?

Comment: Who sent this to you, and what did they say it was for? That might be useful context.

Comment: that's seems right, I got HI so far

Answer (score 5):

Daniel S. was correct,

I need to trace them out on my keyboard (I assume the 'keys' was the keys on my keyboard).

First word:

> rfvgyhnbgt -> HI

Second word:

> rfvgyhntgbnjuyefvgbhu -> HOW

Third word:

> cfthngrfvtygnrfvtyghbn -> ARE

Fourth word:

> tghybygbnjutgbnju -> YOU

Comment: That's really clever; well done!